# IntelliJ - Is there a way to prevent the auto-formatter from collapsing spaces between items in an array?

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, whitespace

On my project, we have some areas where our data is a 2D array, and we like to line up our columns to make it easy to see which data is in which column.  For example:

```
iit("returns #expected if input is #input", (test) => {
    expect(subject.apply(test.input)).to.equal(test.expected)
}).where([
    ["input",    "expected"],
    [null,       ""        ],
    [undefined,  ""        ],
    [[],         ""        ],
    [7,          42        ],       
})
```

However, IntelliJ's auto formatter likes to remove the whitespace between items in an array, converting the above into:

```
iit("returns #expected if input is #input", (test) => {
    expect(subject.apply(test.input)).to.equal(test.expected)
}).where([
    ["input", "expected"],
    [null, ""],
    [undefined, ""],
    [[], ""],
    [7, 42],        
})
```

This is less readable.  Is there a way to configure the auto formatter to leave spaces alone in this situation?

Our primary target language for this is TypeScript, but it would also be handy in Java or in general.  I've explored the Editor -> Code Style part of IntelliJ's settings without finding anything, and haven't found any answers via search engines, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no way to do this, please vote for [WEB-41045](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-41045) to be notified on any progress with this feature